# Generate and publish scripts wizard - SQL Server instance migration

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use Generate and publish scripts wizard on a DB to get the necessary scripts to perform a migration. I ticked the option to script logins and objects, and logins and server roles are being scripted (including permissions), however, I have noticed that server-permissions (such as Alter any linked server permission) are not scripted and no option in advanced is available to do so.

Are there any other objects/permissions which are not scripted by this tool that I have missed?

Do you use any other tool(s) which may cover everything for migrations?

Comment: Server level permissions aren't database level; if you're scripting out a database then no, you won't get server level related permissions, or objects (like triggers).

Comment: That was my guess too, but server roles and login memberships are scripted

Answer (score 0):

Generate and publish scripts wizard just use for inner database objects.for server level objects you need to script each object that you need to migrate, **separately** like logins,linked servers .. .

Comment: Is there any tool for this?

Comment: I use redgate sql compare for database level objects. It,s very nice tool.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything that covers logins, server role memberships and server role permissions?